# Calling member methods from class object in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this bit of code:

```
class ABC:
    def test():
        print('Hi there')

ABC.test()
```

Which outputs:

```
Hi there
```

Whereas this fails:

```
ABC().test()
TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
# Makes sense
```

We know that when we invoke a `classmethod` like `<classname>.<methodname>()`, the class is implicitly passed as an argument to it, but `test` here takes no arguments.

Why don't we see a `TypeError` because of the unexpected argument? Isn't the class passed as an argument to `test`?

Comment: You don't have a classmethod. You simply have a method that can only be used unbound.

Comment: Since `def test()` is not `def test(self)` it does not take the class instance it was called from as an argument.  If you replace your test function with one that takes the self argument you should get the `TypeError` you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is passed to `test()` because functions do not bind to anything when accessed to a class. It remains *unbound*, you get the original function:

```
>>> class ABC:
...     def test():
...         print('Hi there')
...
>>> ABC.test
<function ABC.test at 0x1082706c0>
```

You can call functions directly, provided you pass in the right number of arguments. Here that is 0, so `ABC.test()` succeeds.

It is not a `classmethod`, that would require decorating it with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) (or otherwise producing a `classmethod` object and storing it as an attribute of the class), at which point accessing the attribute binds the function to the class object, producing a bound `method`:

```
>>> class ABC:
...     @classmethod
...     def test():
...         print('Hi there')
...
>>> ABC.test
<bound method ABC.test of <class '__main__.ABC'>>
```

Calling this results in an exception:

```
>>> ABC.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Functions can be bound too, but only when accessed on an instance of the class. Both `function` and `classmethod` objects implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and accessing attributes on classes and on instances will trigger the `__get__` method on descriptors. But only `classmethod` objects return a bound method in that case, functions just return themselves.

Specifically, the [descriptor `__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) is passed `None` for the first argument, the object to bind to, when the attribute access is on a class, and the instance when accessed on the instance. `classmethod().__get__()` ignores the instance argument and produces a method object that binds to the second argument (`owner`). Functions return `self` when the first argument is `None`, or a method object that binds to the instance otherwise:

```
>>> def foo(boundto='nothing'):
...     print(f'Bound to {boundto}')
...
>>> foo.__get__('instance', 'owner')()
Bound to instance
>>> foo.__get__(None, 'owner')()
Bound to nothing
>>> classmethod(foo).__get__('instance', 'owner')()
Bound to owner
>>> classmethod(foo).__get__(None, 'owner')()
Bound to owner
```

Comment: But 1. Does Python 3 have unbound methods? 2. Why is the instance still passed to the function when it's called like `ABC().test()`?

Comment: No, Python 3 does not have unbound methods. Functions just return themselves instead.